# How to buy an Indian railways add-on ticket for a child?

Tags: tickets, indian-railways

I bought confirmed tickets for us online. After, we decided to take friend's child with us, age 6. Is it possible to buy a ticket for him on same PNR or do we need new one; a seat isn't necessary.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do so online. Infact you cannot even book a ticket if a child below 12 is the sole traveller and you have not opted for berth (50% fare). Your best bet would be to take a printout of electronic reservation slip to nearest booking office and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You have to buy a separate ticket for the same. Once a PNR is generated, you cant add people, but can cancel the passengers.